# Once dismissed the boostrap vue alert, it's not working again

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to build a *global alert component* with *bootstrap vue alert* . I am using `vuex` store to maintain the state of alert .

Below is my alert component `Alert.vue`

```
<template>
  <b-alert show :variant="variant" dismissible> {{ message }} </b-alert>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    variant: String,
    message: String
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  name: "Alert",

  methods: {},
  computed: {}
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Below is my `vuex` store

```
const alert = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    variant: "",
    message: "",
    showAlert: false
  },
  getters: {
    variant: state => state.variant,
    message: state => state.message,
    showAlert: state => state.showAlert
  },
  mutations: {
    setSuccessvariant(state) {
      state.variant = "success";
    },
    setDangervariant(state) {
      state.variant = "danger";
    },
    setMessage(state, message) {
      state.message = message;
    },
    showAlert(state) {
      state.showAlert = true;
    },
    hideAlert(state) {
      state.showAlert = false;
    }
  },
  actions: {}
};

export default alert;
```

I am calling the alert component in another component like below

```
<alert v-if="showAlert" :message="message" :variant="variant"></alert>
```

showAlert is computed in this component as

```
showAlert() {
      return this.$store.getters["alert/showAlert"];
   }
```

**This works only first time. Alert opens when I trigger it for the first time. Once I click on dismiss icon, I could not get back the alert.**

Comment: I believe (have to check the docs to confirm) that once an alert is dismissed it is destroyed. To get it back you should recreate it

Comment: What are the requirements? Once alert is dismissed the showAlert state is set to false as it is supossed to be and the alert disappears. If you want a new alert message to be display you need to to the necessary mutations to update alert message and change the showAlert state to true.

Comment: i making showAlert to true whenever user perform the action ..      `this.$store.commit("alert/showAlert");`.But how the dismissed alert makes the showAlert false? because i am not handling that in my code.

Comment: dismissable will make the alert disappaear from the dom. You could instead of using that just use a custom close button and listen to a click event on it and in your own event listener change your redux state. An alternative is to listen to your dismissable alerts dismiss event and there set the showAlert to false, and once that is back to true a new alert will be rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the `show` property with `v-model` so that when you click the dismiss button the value of `showAlert` gets updated in vuex store:

```
<b-alert 
  v-model="showAlert" 
  :variant="variant" 
  dismissible
> {{ message }} 
</b-alert>

...

computed: {
  showAlert() {
    get() {
      this.$store.getters["alert/showAlert"]
    },
    set(value) {
      // MODIFY THIS MUTATION
      this.$store.commit("setShowAlert", value)
    }
  }
}
```

#### Vuex:

```
mutations: {
  setShowAlert(state, value) {
    state.showAlert = value
  }, 
}
```

Also try replacing `v-if="showAlert"` with `v-show="showAlert"` perhaps you have some issue with component re-rendering

Comment: did the changes still not working .. getting below error while dismissing the alert **unknown mutation type: alert/showAlert**below is my alert component

Comment: @Saradha it just means you don't have mutation with that name in your vuex store. I updated the code. If it still doesn't work just change the mutation name in the computed property so it matches that mutation name in your vuex store.

Comment: @Saradha no problem, glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

You have to control what happens on dismissed event. Component show attribute does not accept anything other than true or false what is rarely a thing you really use as a trigger to show the alert.

So do NOT use a v-model bound to a string attribute that you expect to be not null as long as alert has to be shown. It will not work.

This component is not able to evaluate non-boolean flags.

Use v-bind:show as shown bellow

```
    <b-alert v-bind:show="error!=null" 
dismissible variant="danger" @dismissed="error=null">
        {{error}}
    </b-alert>
```

When alert is dismissed it will set error to null and it will flip the state of show condition. Then if you again set error to something, it will properly flip the state.